# How to get the dom element as an argument using data-bind attribute - knockout to manipulate with in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, knockout.js

I want to pass the content of an li element as an argument to my function while using data-bind attribute, click method. 
For example

```
 <ul>
     <li data-bind='click: titleClick(argument)'>(CONTENT)</li>
 </ul>
```

What to put instead of argument to pass (CONTENT) to my titleClick function?
This is my processing in the js file

```
var MapProcess = function(){
    this.titleClick = function(titleName){
        for (var i = 0; i<model.markers.length; i++){
            if (titleName == model.markers[i].title){
                var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({          
                });
                infoWindow.setContent(model.markers[i].buborek)
                infoWindow.open(map, model.markers[i]);
                break;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

I want the parameter titleName in my function above to equal the content retrieved from the html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "the content retrieved from the html"? Is there an `input` box in the `li`?

Comment: No I meant the content that I want to retrieve from the html dom element. Sorry for the language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument in a click handler will be the click event. From that you can get the target element and its associated content.

https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html

```js
var MapProcess = function() {
  this.titleClick = function(data, event) {
    console.log(event.target.textContent);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new MapProcess());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li data-bind='click: titleClick'>(CONTENT)</li>
</ul>
```